# Check if redirect url exists

Tags: django, url, design-patterns

After login user should be redirected to the `?next=%s` url. I want to check if specified url mapped to an existant view. There is `reverse()` function for getting url by view, i need v.v.
So, i need the function that Django executes for url pattern match.

I see, the question is simple, but i could not find the answer in google.

Comment: Could you just throw the reverse() call in a try-except block?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve, Resolver404
try:
    resolve(path)
except Resolver404:
    'not found'
```

Comment: [As of Django 1.10, importing from django.core.urlresolvers is deprecated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/releases/1.10/#id3). The updated import is `from django.urls import resolve, Resolver404`.